How can i stop this jitter from the camera in webots?
I'm using the Surveyor SRV-1 robot in Webots to navigate a custom map I've created. Everything runs smoothly at lower speeds, but as soon as I increase the speed to more than 0.2 m/s, I start experiencing noticeable camera jitter. Usually it happens more when I am moving forward and rotating at the same time.
issue -> https://imgur.com/a/srF1KA5
Any help is appreciated.
edit1: video highlighting issue with visible bounding boxes -> https://imgur.com/a/KJIU1tH

Maybe this problem is caused by the simulation’s time step being too large or the camera’s frame rate being too low?
Try to reduce a timestep to 10-12ms.
Reducing the timestep will help, because it made the physics engine update more frequently. At higher speeds, this means the simulation can keep up better with fast movements and interactions, so things like collisions are more accurate, and you don’t get that jittery effect

the world timestep is 24. I'm not sure what the camera framerate is. But it seems like for some reason the wheel bounding box is causing issues with the floor? So it jitters aggressivel at high speeds. My bad, this might not be a camera specific issue. I'll post another video with the bounding boxes visible

@RahulMehta , I updated my answer, check please, is it helpful?

Reducing the world timestep and the initializing timestep in my code to 10 significantly improved it, and it is playable at high speeds. I'm going to accept this as the answer. Could you explain how that made it work, though?

Edited the answer.

awesome! thank you!
